# How to port a module for Ruby to Python

Tags: python, ruby, sass

Or how can I learn Ruby quickly? Is there a pattern to port a ruby module to python?

I want to add scope system to Sass, but I know little about ruby, and when I started, I found the contents of a module are in several files, there are a lot of variables or classes undefined but referenced.

What's the difference between require keyword and the python's import?

Or at least, is there a ruby IDE that can tell me where is a module, class, variable defined like PyDev does?

Answer (score 1):

There probably are IDE out there that have a bit of code help built in, but I usually don't find I need it. Most Ruby libraries have a certain structural pattern to them. Especially gems by design. You might not notice it at first if you are new to Ruby but once you get the hang of it; things are quite easy to navigate by the naming alone.

To the original intent of your question. I don't think there is an easy way to port a piece of Ruby code like SASS to python in a snap. It would require adequate knowledge of both languages to translate it well. In a way it's kind of like the job of a translator, if you don't know either language well you won't make a lot of sense by what you are producing.

In Ruby require loads a file and executes it. A library will usually have a file named like the library that will include other parts of its components, to make the modules within known.

```
# req.rb
puts 'Hello World'

# irb
1.9.2p290 :001 > require './req.rb'
Hello World
=> true
```

So it will basically do the same for you as import in python. You name a module you would like to use and it will work for you after requiring/importing it(given it is known to your load paths). 
If you are looking for an equivalent to the python

```
from <modulename> import *
```

you should refer to

```
include <modulename>
```

Which isn't frowned upon as much in ruby as it is in python.

Hope this answers most of your questions.